# Thermodynamic control or kinetic control?

Tags: organic-chemistry, stability, resonance

[image: This is the image]

In my notes, it is written that the case 1 product will be major one. The explanation given is as follows:-

> However, since the pi clouds of alkenes are perpendicular to each other, the resonance factor will be reduced. Till the time resonance occurs, water would have already attacked the positive charge centre and hence the thermodynamic-controlled product will be favoured.

I don't get this thing!

Comment: RE: "Thermodynamic control or kinetic control?" That is just a bad way to look at reactions. All reactions are controlled both by thermodynamics and kinetics.

Comment: This appears weird to me since the thermodynamic control vs kinetic control  pathways are used to describe as to what will be the major product. Let me elaborate. The kinetic controlled reaction is one which "happens faster but leads to less stable products" and the thermodynamic controlled reaction is the one which "happens slower but leads to the more stable products." But in this example, the kinetic controlled reaction appears to be the thermodynamic controlled reaction as well.

Comment: The comparison of kinetic control and thermodynamic control is supposed to show you why reactions do not give you the most stable products. It should also introduce you to activation barriers, and what not. I am not sure if your class notes are correct. But take it with a grain of salt, it has been a while since I took organic chemistry

Comment: Well I can safely say that my class notes are correct. I just don't get the explanation.